# Xna Should I create bullets inside the weapon class

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, hittest

I have my gameplay.cs that spawns everything basically including bullets.

the gameplay needs access to the bullets to hit detection with terrain or other characters.

I would rather instantiate the bullet inside the weapon class rather than the gameplay class.

But that would mean I cannot keep track of my bullet to do the hittest....

Need some guidance here, expect me to be a total noob in C# and xna.

Comment: Please don't cross post across multiple Stack Exchange sites. If your question on Game Developers - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10198/xna-should-i-create-bullets-inside-the-weapon-class - was in the wrong place it would have been migrated for you.

Comment: Sorry, just thought this would be more a general question than just gaming xna...

Comment: You can always flag your own question for a moderator to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not expose a gameplay member to add new entities from the outside (e.g. the weapon class)?

Essentially something like this:

```
private void OnAttack(object sender, SomeEventArg e)
{
    gameplay.CreateEntity(BazookaProjectileClass, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz);
}
```

Edit:
You shouldn't create your bullets in the gameplay class cause that should be under the weapon's control only. The weapon defines the kind of projectiles or effects to add. If you'd handle that in the gameplay class, why use different/custom weapon class(es) at all?

Comment: Interesting but can you give me some more information on the CreateEntity like I said, I'm a noob... or some link to more information would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: hmm I'm guessing CreateEntity is your own custom class... But I ain't sure how to use the event listeners .... Mind giving me some more information on that ? thanks.

Comment: `CreateEntity` would be a method to create a new object of the given class and add it to your entity list or whatever you're using. In my example an "entity" is just a game object - a bullet, grenade, smoke cloud or whatever.

Comment: Ignore the custom `OnAttack` event. It's just a made up example. You'd just place the call wherever you'd like to create the object. Also note that CreateEntity is not a class, it's just a method/function of the `gameplay` class that is declared as `public`.